# Having CORS when using Google Adsense in React Firebase web app

Tags: html, reactjs, firebase, cors, adsense

I want to add google adsense to my react web. I am using the library [react-adsense](https://github.com/hustcc/react-adsense).

However, I got this error while I want to add the google adsense script in my html file:

`Access to Script at 'http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.`

Here is how I added the script:

```
<script crossorigin="anonymous" async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
```

**Update #1**
I am using firebase to host my website

Comment: Don't use adsense. Deploy a "call to action". You're not gonna make any money unless you have a gazillion visitors. ...just my 2 cents (I researched this myself for my site)

Comment: @RonRoyston what do you recommend to replace Adsense?

Comment: nothing. as far as I could tell it's nearly impossible to make any money that way. ...unless you can generate tens of thousands of hits/day or minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test Adsense locally you may try one of these options:

1- use data-adtest="on"

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>

<ins class="adsbygoogle"
 data-adtest="on"></ins>
<script>
  (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

2- Use google_adtest="on"; (synchronous)

```
<script type="text/javascript">google_adtest="on";</script>
<script src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
```

3- Use an extension (chrome example) [like this one](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog). Or try another browser.

4- If none works, you may try doing a reverse proxy with proxy_pass in nginx - in order to "simulate" that you are visiting from an allowed origin and editing your /etc/hosts (not sure it works though).

```
server {
  listen       80;
  server_name  mydomain.com;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is my developing website: https://devtool-691c7.firebaseapp.com/dashboard/common. I planned to put it on firebase web hosting. I have tried option 3. It sometimes works but i can't guarantee my users is using that extension. What can I do?

Comment: @ykn121 You are having the issue only because you are running this on localhost. The options I’m suggesting are just for testing in development environment...

Comment: Any suggestions for production environment?

Comment: Normally it should work like you wrote it. You may try first with a real domain name that you are not using, just for making sure

Comment: My bad. I set the `crossorigin` parameter to my <script> tag. That results in this error

Comment: Yes sorry, I forgot to mention but indeed needs to be removed like in my code. Cheers thanks for the upvote