# Why google adsense script keep returning CORS error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, adsense

I'm trying to put adsense on my webpage built by react.
Auto ads works fine, but manual ads returns CORS error both on my dev environment and production.

`Access to script at 'https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js' from origin 'http://localhost:3050' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

I put script tag at index.html.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ko">

<head>
  <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
  <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=xxxxxxxx"></script>
  <script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];

    function gtag() {
      dataLayer.push(arguments);
    }
    gtag('js', new Date());
    gtag('config', 'xxxxxxxx');
  </script>
  <script crossorigin async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
</body>

</html>
```

And jsx file is like this.

```html
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid'

const MyPage = (props) => {
   
  useEffect(() => {
    (window.adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
  }, []);

  return (
    <Grid
      container
      justify="center"
    >        
        <Grid item xl={3} lg={2}>
            <div style={{
              display: 'flex',
              justifyContent: 'center',
              minWidth: 160,
              maxWidth: 320,
              height: '100%',
              alignItems: 'center',
              flexDirection: 'column'
            }}
            >
              <ins
                className="adsbygoogle"
                style={{ display: 'inline-block', width: '160px', height: '600px' }}
                data-ad-client="xxxxxxxxxx"
                data-ad-slot="xxxxxxxxxxx"
              />
            </div>
        </Grid>  
        <Grid item xl={3} lg={2}>
          <div style={{
            display: 'flex',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            minWidth: 160,
            maxWidth: 320,
            height: '100%',
            alignItems: 'center',
            flexDirection: 'column'
          >
            <ins
              className="adsbygoogle"
              style={{ display: 'inline-block' }}
              data-ad-client="xxxxxxxxxxx"
              data-ad-slot="xxxxxxxxxxxx"
              data-ad-format="auto"
              data-full-width-responsive="true"
            />
          </div>
          )}
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
};

export default MyPage;
```

I tried 
[Having CORS when using Google Adsense in React Firebase web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49347921/having-cors-when-using-google-adsense-in-react-firebase-web-app) and tried to use react-adsense library.
However, None of them worked out. 
I'm stuck on this for 3 days. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is this: If you haven't already, install the Moesif Orign & CORS Changer extension for Chrome and turn CORS off. If you're still being blocked locally, the issue might be something else and you can address whatever it is head on. If the extension successfully stops you from being blocked, you still need to adjust things so CORS won't block your app in development.

Comment: If all else fails you may have to create middleware that applies a "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" header to every response from the server.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference I see from what I worked on previously is that I put the...

```
<script crossorigin async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
```

...not in the head section.  I placed it in between hte  tags.

Not sure that will help in total just one thing I have noticed that was different from what I setup in the past when trying to implement AdSense in my react app.  I do hope that helps though.

Comment: Also make sure you have added CORS headings to allow access.